# Pass Oauth to a Rest service to utilise it (i.e. continue authenticating)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, oauth

This is a question related to the [Xero Api](http://developer.xero.com/code-samples/libraries/using-the-xero-api-with-c/), but might be general enough for stackoverflow.

I'm using the [Xero .Net Wrapper Library](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI.Net), particularly [this](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI.Net/blob/master/source/XeroApi.ConsoleTests/Program.cs) class which uses the [PublicApplicationRunner](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI.Net/blob/master/source/XeroApi.ConsoleTests/PublicApplicationRunner.cs).

*Narrowing things down*, the OAuth authentication follows this approach (sections commented `1.`,`2.`,`3.`,`4.`):

```
private const string UserAgent = "Xero.API v1.0 (Public App Testing)";
private const string ConsumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
private const string ConsumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

public static Repository CreateRepository()
{
    IOAuthSession consumerSession = new XeroApiPublicSession(
        UserAgent, 
        ConsumerKey, 
        ConsumerSecret, 
        new InMemoryTokenRepository());

    consumerSession.MessageLogger = new DebugMessageLogger();

    string callback_url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:41000/xxx/xxx/xero/";

    Uri uri = new Uri(callback_url);

    // 1. Get a request token
    IToken requestToken = consumerSession.GetRequestToken(uri);

    // 2. Get the user to log into Xero using the request token 
    // in the query string
    string authorisationUrl = consumerSession.GetUserAuthorizationUrl();
    Process.Start(authorisationUrl);

    // 3. Get the use to enter the authorisation code from Xero
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the code you were given in Xero:");
    var verificationCode = Console.ReadLine();

    // 4. Use the request token and verification code to get an access token
    AccessToken accessToken;

    try
    {
        accessToken = consumerSession.ExchangeRequestTokenForAccessToken(
                verificationCode.Trim()
                );
    }
    catch (OAuthException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Report);
        return null;
    }

    // Wrap the authenticated consumerSession in the repository...
    return new Repository(consumerSession);
}
```

The above is a Console Application. I'm trying to skip the user from having to manually input the `verificationCode` (that would have been displayed via the browser after the user logins to Xero) via the console - i.e. I'm trying to skip to section `4.`.

Xero allows to have a callback url which is actioned upon authorization. So instead of waiting at `3.`, a callback is actioned and the relevant authorization information to complete (*not start over*) the oauthentication gets sent to a WCF Rest service:

```
?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&oauth_verifier=#######
&org=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The problem is this information is on a service which is on a different thread (well, project even) from the initial `CreateRepository()`.

What would be the best approach to pass this information back to the console application? (from the WCF Rest service).

**Short Summary:**

What is the best approach (if possible) to pass information from a WCF Rest service (which uses a console app as a host/runner) to a Console Application?

*(Kudos for reading this long question)*

Answer (score 0):

You can set the callback url to localhost(127.0.0.1:anyport). Then you can listen to localhost and get the verification code from there. No need for user to manually copy paste the verification code to your console

---

You can set the `oauth_callback` parameter to 127.0.0.1:8080  while obtaining the request token. Referred from [here](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step1)

Comment: Thanks @Anirudha, that's a good lead. I can listen to localhost, but the messages are received by the (WCF Rest) service - what would be the approach to pass the message back into the (host) Console application.