# How to pass a string from WCF Rest service to the (host) console application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, oauth

*I'm following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25883444/1972457).*

I'm using the [Xero .Net Wrapper](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI.Net), where (much like twitter, facebook, etc.) I'm trying to get the user to authorize (oAuthenticate) an App by logging into Xero.

Currently, when I run my project the user is prompted to log into Xero, after logging in instead of asking the user to (manually) enter the oauth verifier code into the console app it is passed via a **callback url** that gets received by my WCF Rest service.

**Question:** 

How can I pass a string received by a WCF service to the console application that is running that service?

---

Here's a sample of my project solution:

Service Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "/teststr/?string={aStr}")]
string TestString(string aStr);
```

Service implementation

```
public string TestString(string aStr = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The TestString() method was called at {0}"
        + "\n\rThe given string was {1}\n\r"
        , DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss")
        , aStr);

    return aStr;
}
```

Program, i.e. Main():

```
// Step 1 Create a URI to serve as the base address.
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ServiceSample/");

// Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance
WebServiceHost selfHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestService), baseAddress);

try
{
    // Step 3 Add a service endpoint.
    selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(),
        "TestService");

    // Step 4 Enable metadata exchange.
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    //smb.HttpGetBinding = "";
    selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);


    // Step 5 Start the service.
    selfHost.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
    selfHost.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException ce)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
    selfHost.Abort();
}
```

When the `TestString()` method gets called, is it possible to pass the `aStr` variable back to the `Main()` method?

*Ultimately this would allow me to return the oauth verifier code to the place where the OAuthentication process started.*

Comment: I doubt it, at least not without a lot of (unnecessary) work.  If you want to validate that the method works, you could always step through the code in the debugger.  Or write a simple client to test with and examine the return the client gets.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try putting a `Console.WriteLine()` call in the service, but I don't know if that will print to the console or not.  But since you ultimately want the data returned to a client of some sort, it's just as simple (IMO) to write a quick client to test it with - or test it in the browser, since it's a RESTful service.